# ubuntu - mount iso case sensitive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, iso-image, filenames

I got a ISO which contains case-sensitive file/directory-names.

When mounting it on my Ubuntu 12.04 system using `mount -o loop`, all filenames are lowercase. There is an option called `map=off`, but when using that, all filenames are uppercase. What I found out during my research is, that ISO9660 doesn't support case-sensitive filenames by default. However, there is a extension called [Joliet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_%28file_system%29) which does. My iso seems to be using joliet as it has case sensitive filenames when mounted on windows/mac os x. [mkisofs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man8/mkisofs.8.html) does also support joliet.

However, I was not able to find a way to mount the ISO using joliet. How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Dmesg does log `[  149.293945] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1`. Not sure why it isn't used though.

**Edit2:**
You can find the ISO here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/files/Bootable_ISO/CloverISO-1914.tar.lzma/download

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that the Joliet extensions have been enabled for your kernel. I imagine they are since you are using Ubuntu but check anyway, just to be sure:

```
grep -i joliet /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

That *should* return this line:

```
CONFIG_JOLIET=y
```

If the file is missing, try searching for joliet in `/proc/config.gz`. I don't have this file on my system, I am repeating what I read [here](http://www.linux.com/community/forums/storage/how-to-enable-joliet-file-system-support/limit/20/offset/0).

Now, assuming you do have joliet enabled, my guess is that you have a CD that is not Joliet. I tried to replicate your issue by creating a joliet iso of two case sensitive files:

```
$ ls foo/
Aaaaa  Bbbbb

$ genisoimage -J -R -o foo.iso foo/
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
Total translation table size: 0
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 323
Total directory bytes: 0
Path table size(bytes): 10
Max brk space used 0
181 extents written (0 MB)

$ sudo mount ./foo.iso baz/
mount: warning: baz/ seems to be mounted read-only.  <-- ignore this, not a problem
$ ls baz
Aaaaa  Bbbbb
```

In other words, as long as an image was created using the Joliet extensions it should be mounted case sensitive by default. I am *really* not an expert on image file systems but perhaps the problem is not Joliet but something completely different. Can you mount case sensitive if you do the same steps I did above?

---

EDIT:

I downloaded your iso and get the same behavior you describe, I can't mount it case sensitive. I did find a possible reason though. I ran `isoinfo` on both your file and mine:

```
$ isoinfo -d -i Clover-1914-X64.iso | grep Joliet
Joliet with UCS level 1 found
$ isoinfo -d -i foo.iso | grep Joliet
Joliet with UCS level 3 found
```

I have no idea what the difference between Joliet levels 1 and 3 is but I suspect that is why your iso is not working properly. This might at least give you a new avenue of research.

Comment: Hi, you are right! Actually, when creating a .iso myself it does work. No idea why this iso I am trying to mount doesn't work. I added the link to it in my OP. Maybe you can try it out! Thanks :-)

Comment: @Zulakis see updated question.